# Database session problem with login and logout using Yii2 DbSession

Tags: php, session, yii, yii2

I'm trying to implement the [DbSession](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-dbsession), as it is explained [here](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/issues/92), I've implemented the two custom fields as shown here:

```
'session' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\DbSession',
    'writeCallback' => function ($session) {
        return [
            'user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id,
            'last_write' => time(),
        ];
    },
],
```

The problem I face is simple yet I seems that I only find ugly solutions, as the session is updated in every action, when I try to logout, or login (I do an ajax call to check things before login) the aplicacion crashes because the user is guest and there is no `user->id`.

I can do ugly solutions, but I rather understand how it works, or how to implement in a way that only triggers once the user is still logged in.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the error message?

Comment: @lubosdz as I said as the user is guest, there is no user, then there is no id, so it crashes.

Comment: What do you mean by "it crashes"? Error message would be helpful.

Comment: @rob006 Im not on my computer, but is the classic error of accesing a property of an object that does not exist as `Yii::$app->user` is null/undefined `Yii::$app->user->id` crashes with (I think the message is more or less : Trying to get property of non-object ). But I mean, it has no importance, I know what the error is and why it happen or how to solve it in an ungly way, what Im trying to archieve here is to configure in a right way that only triggers as it logged in.

Comment: `Yii::$app->user` should be available regardless of whether the user is logged in or not. You have an chicken-egg problem (`writeCallback` is called before `user` component is fully initialized) if you get such error.

Comment: @rob006 Sorry rob you are right, my miss, I had a long weekend, the problem was in the database as the user_id was required, and when it was null it crashed as the query couldn't execute.

Comment: Then what `user_id` do you want to insert if session in started for guest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `Yii::$app->user->id,` attempts to load user [identity](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authentication#implementing-identity) which always fails if the user is not logged in. Just check whether user is a guest:

```
'session' => [
   'class' => 'yii\web\DbSession',
   'writeCallback' => function ($session) {
      return [
         'user_id' => Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? null : Yii::$app->user->id,
         'last_write' => time(),
      ];
   },
],
```

Comment: This will not change anything, since `Yii::$app->user->id` will return `null` if user is a guest.

Comment: I already know that, as I explain, this is an ugly solution, as the database is updated with the `session->user_id` as null. Im trying to find how to prevent this action to fire before login and after logout.